# Spin a Div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, animate.css

I want to be able to spin a Div around using jQuery. I have created the effect with pure CSS -  see here

http://jsfiddle.net/9twvF/

```
<div class="clientcontainer">
    <div class="clientcard hl">
        <div class="front face">Front Panel</div>
        <div class="back face center">Back Panel</div>
    </div>
</div>


.clientcontainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}


.clientcontainer {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.clientcard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.clientcontainer:hover .hl, .clientcontainer.hover_effect .hl {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

But instead of using CSS and it working on hover over. I want jQuery to be able to animate the div with the same effect but it do it say on the click of a button.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a jquery plugin called `flip` if you want to simulate the effect

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I started playing with stuff and worked out how to do this

http://jsfiddle.net/9twvF/5/

```
<div class="clientcontainer">
    <div class="clientcard hl">
        <div class="front face">Front Panel</div>
        <div class="back face center">Back Panel</div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="rotate">rotate</a>


.clientcontainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}


.clientcontainer {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.clientcard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}

$("#rotate").click(function() {
    $(".clientcard").css({
     '-webkit-transform' : 'rotateY(-180deg)',
     '-moz-transform' : 'rotateY(-180deg)',  
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotateY(-180deg)',  
       '-o-transform' : 'rotateY(-180deg)',  
          'transform' : 'rotateY(-180deg)'
    });
});
```

Just in case anybody wants the answer. I will also look at jquery flip, it might be easier than what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

Just connecting div click event to css style change shoudl do the trick.

```
 $("div.button").click( function() {
     $("div.background").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(-190deg)')
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try [jQuery Flippy](http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/). I think it should help you achieve what you want.